# Java Copy Constructor ArrayLists

Tags: java, constructor, copy

I am trying to create a copy constructor considering the object is mutable. My copy constructor is wrong; I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Please do NOT tell me to use `clone()`. How would I complete the copy constructor in this situation? I am new to Java and would really appreciate any help.

```
public class MyList {


public ArrayList<Cool> people;

/**
 * "people" variable as a new (empty) ArrayList of Cool objects.
 */
public MyPersonList()
{
    people = new ArrayList<Cool>(0);    
}


/**
 * A copy constructor which makes the right kind of copy considering
 * a Cool is mutable.
 */
public MyList(MyList other) 
{
    people = new ArrayList<Cool>(); 

    for(Cool p:people)
    {   
        people.add(p);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12):

Note: Cloning the lists, isn't the same as cloning the elements in the list.

None of these approaches work the way you want them to:

```
//1
people = new ArrayList<Cool>(other.people);

//2
people = new ArrayList<Cool>();
for(Cool p : other.people) {
    people.add(p);
}
```

The approaches above will fill `people` such that it contains the same elements as `other.people`.

However, you don't want it to contain the same elements. You want to fill it with clones of the elements in `other.people`.

The best approach would be something like this:

```
people = new ArrayList<Cool>(other.people.size());
for(Cool p : other.people) {
    people.add((Cool)p.clone());
}
```

Make sure `Cool` implements `Cloneable`. Override `clone()` if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Simply: you are iterating over `people` but you should iterate over `other.people` variable.

Just a note: `ArrayList` already provides a constructor to add all items of another collection:

```
ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

so:

```
people = new ArrayList<Cool>(other.people);
```

is enough.

Comment: `other.people`. Perhaps add a `getPeople()`/`people()` method that returns a copy of the list.

Comment: when I do other.people, so that it is people = new ArrayList<Cool>(other.people);   it is incorrect

Comment: @qkad I deleted my comment. I just realized what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
public MyList(MyList other) 
{
    people = new ArrayList<Cool>(); 

    for(Cool p:people)
    {   
        people.add(p);
    }

}
```

change it to :

```
public MyList(MyList other) 
{
    people = new ArrayList<Cool>(); 

    for(Cool p : other.people)
    {   
        people.add(p);
    }

}
```